# Ducking Notifications When Playing a sound

Tags: c#, cscore

I am looking for a way to reduce the volume of other applications so that my application can then play a sound to alert the user of something.

Windows already has a Ducking Behavior which reduces volume of music during a phone call. However, I am unable to find any references (especially in C#) as to how I can have my application trigger this Ducking Behavior as well as have the operating system ignore my application when I trigger it.

Does anyone know how I can trigger the ducking behavior for other applications?

Thanks